# How to get a list in Action Method in MVC MVC and then pass each instance to View?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I have got a list of students in my action method and i want to pass each student instance to a view inside a foreach loop something like that

```
    foreach(var student in Students)
    {
       return View(student);
       // instead of return i have also tried this View(student) but it also doesnt work 
    }
```

Is it possible?
Actually i dont want to pass complete list to view instead of it I want to pass each student instance to a view by `[httpget]`and after getting its updated information like marks and grades in `[httppost]` i would like to send next student to view and get its updated information. It would be much easier for user to enter details of one student at a time instead of dealing with a complete list

Comment: This is definitely not the right way to implement this, since it will only return the result for the first student in Students. May be you need to implement a MVC Control rendering a student.

Comment: Just declare a list in your model class , and assign the student details list to that list and then you can get that simply in view, n need to pass separately, just pass the object of your model class

Comment: Thanks for your response actually i dont want to pass a complete list to my view all i want is to pass a single instance of student from the list to my view and after getting its details like marks,grades in `[httppost]` i would like to pass next student to the view from my list

Comment: You need to edit your question to explain what your trying to achieve, not in comments.

Comment: Then you need return a `Student` based on an `ID` property. If the `ID` that you pass to the GET method is `null`, return the first student. When you POST, get the ID of the next student and redirect to the GET method, passing the new `ID` and get the return the student based on that `ID`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as object to method

```
// from your controller

List<yourobject> list = new List<yourobject>();

return View(list);


// in your view

@model List<yourobject>

// and property Model is type of List<yourobject>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <span>@item.Name</span>//example
}
```

Also you can use the dynamic object ViewBag to pass data from Controllers to Views.
example :

```
ViewBag.MyStudentList = myStudentList;

@ViewBag.MyList

// e.g.
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyStudentList ) { 
//you get data here
}
```

Else:

Declare a list in model class , and assign the student details to it , and include that model in view and access it

```
public class yourviewmodelStudent
{
    public SubjectGradesViewModel()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Student>();
    }

    public List<Student> Studentdetails { get; set; }
}
//class that represnt your Student model

public class Student 
{
    public int Classnumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Studentdetails { get; set; }
}


//then in controller 

 var model = new yourviewmodelStudent();

model.Studentdetails =//assign your list 

then 
return View(model);

In view you get this list simply:
```

Comment: Thanks for your response actually i dont want to pass a complete list to my view all i want is to pass a single instance of student from the list to my view and after getting its details like marks,grades in `[httppost]` i would like to pass next student to the view from my list

Comment: you mean a single student details ? and i hope your ultimate aim is pass all student details to view ,right ? then why are you trying to pass by single ?? what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: A student has usually 4 to 5 courses in a semester and each course has its final and sessional marks and grade so i want to pass a single student to a view in one time so that user will be able to enter details of single student and then move to next student. Entering the details of all the students on one page would be much difficult for user.

Comment: ok agreed, but still also no need to post one by one,you can post all in single step , and hide all other details and show only 1, and when the user completes the 1 st one show second one to user and so on , this is the normal way to do this. else you can call a function each time when u need student details you can use an ajax call for this.but i think the first method is more simple